# Добавить связь категорий к фильму в Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine

Подскажите, кто работает с doctrine, как в моём случае правильно добавить записи.

Имеется таблица `Category -> id` , name она заполнена категориями.

```
// film.php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="films_categories",
     *              joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="film_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
     *              inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $categories;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addCategories(ArrayCollection $categories){
        dump($categories); die;
        foreach($categories as $category){
            $this->categories->add($category);
        }

    }
```

У меня есть массив с данными:

```
// в цикле заполняю сущность фильм информацией. 
foreach($data as $key => $info) {

            $film = new Film();
            $film->SetTitle($info['title']);

// массив с ключами категорий 
$info['genres'] = ['array key' => 'category key']
```

Категории изначально введены в базу данных в таблицу Category, их порядка 20, таблица с фильмами пустая. У меня есть массив с данными о каждом фильме, а также к каким категориям он относится. Как заполнить поля фильма информацией понятно. А вот как добавить связь с категориями? Наброски кода, которые посчитал что-то могут вам сказать, скинул. Пишите, если ещё какая-то информация нужна.

Получаю

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Entity\Film::addCategories() must be an instance of
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection, instance o

Comment: Вы где-нибудь еще вызываете addCategories() ?

Comment: В цикле это foreach там где добавляю поля в сущность film

Comment: приведите код, который вызывает метод addCategories()

Answer (score 1):

Вот вся функция которая добавляет в базу данных:

```
private function InsertFilmsAndRelations($data)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    foreach($data as $key => $info) {

        $film = new Film();
        $film->SetTitle($info['title']);
        $film->SetSummary(trim($info['summary']));
        $film->SetRating($info['rating']);
        $film->setTrailerUri($info['trailer_uri']);
        $film->setStoryLine(trim($info['story_line']));
        $genres = [];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($info['genres']); $i++){
            $genres[] = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findOneBy(['id' => $info['genres'][$i]]);
        }

        $film->setCategories($genres);
        $em->persist($film);
    }

    $em->flush();

    return true;
}
```

Вот сущность фильм. Та часть которая добавляет категории.

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="films_categories",
 *              joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="film_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
 *              inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
 */
private $categories;

public function __construct(){
    $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Set categories
 *
 * @return category
 */
public function setCategories($categories)
{
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $this->addCategory($category);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function addCategory(Category $category)
{
    $this->categories->add($category);
}
```

Всё как-бы работает как надо только не уверен правильный ли это оптимальный вариант. Также столкнулся с тем что когда в контролере пытаюсь получить все фильмы.

```
    $films = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Film')->findAll();
dump($films);die;
```

хотелось бы получить и все категории к нему.  А вместо получаю :

```
-categories: PersistentCollection {#488 ▼
  -snapshot: []
  -owner: Film {#474}
  -association: array:19 [ …19]
  -em: EntityManager {#414 …11}
  -backRefFieldName: null
  -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#476 …}
  -isDirty: false
  #collection: ArrayCollection {#489 ▼
    -elements: []
  }
  #initialized: false
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно убрать проверку типа в методе addCategories.

```
  public function addCategories($categories)
```

Или же передавать в нее ArrayCollection а не массив, как того требует type hinting.